# use variable in inner Class run

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Hey :) I've got a Problem with Variables. I wanna know how the methode run() can see 'l' and 'a'.

```
public static void startDraw(String[] players) {
    final DrawGame a = new DrawGame(players); 

        for ( Player b : a.getPlayers()){
                 final Player l =  b;
                 Runnable q = new go(); 


                    }
    }

    protected static class go implements Runnable{

        public go(){

        }
        public void run(){
            while (a.finished()!= true){
                l.drawLine();
            }
        }

        Thread t = new Thread(new go()).start();
    }
```

Comment: variable are for someone who use it in the class.

Comment: Are you sure you can access those? IMO you have other variables with a larger scope that have the same name, otherwise this code wouldn't compile.

Comment: wanna let the players draw lines,but they are only given in startDraw

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd give your variables more meaningful names. If you come back to this code in 6 months there's no way you still know what a, b, l or q are.

Comment: it doesn't compile. So do i have to instance DrawGame in run? But then i dont have the players to do it

Comment: one quick question.. Is this code working?

Comment: no it isnt cause the run methode dont know the variable a and l

Comment: how does OP got +1 on the question which is not working???

Comment: @AnkitLamba - My bad. I actually thought that the code was working. A careful observation said otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanna know how the methode run() can see 'l' and 'a'?

Because your inner class `go` is method local inner class and `a` and `l` are method local final variable in the same method `go()`

If you declare the variables final, the inner class knows they won't change, so they can just make a copy of it for private use, which will exist after the original value has been removed from the stack.